# PyQt4: How do you iterate all items in a QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

Currently,  I use the following while loop in a class that inherits QtGui.QListWidget to iterate all items:

```
    i = 0
    while i < self.count():
        item = self.item(i)

        i += 1
```

I was hoping I could use:

```
for item in self.items():
```

but the items() method wants a QMimeData object which I don't know how to construct to return all items.  Is there a cleaner approach than my while loop above?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know what's it with the MIME type either, and I couldn't find a convenience method either. But you could write a simple method like this and be done:

```
def iterAllItems(self):
    for i in range(self.count()):
        yield self.item(i)
```

It's even lazy (a generator).

Comment: Thanks!  What are your thoughts on using xrange here.

Comment: @majgis: My all means, yes. In Python 2, use xrange whenever possible. It's just that I'm usually using Python 3, so I get tend to write Python 3 in my examples.

Answer (score 14):

Just to add my 2 cents, as I was looking for this:

```
itemsTextList =  [str(listWidget.item(i).text()) for i in range(listWidget.count())]
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is old but, I just found out a function [findItems(text, Qt.MatchFlags)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#findItems) in QListWidget. So, to iterate all items:

```
#listWidget is a QListWidget full of items
all_items = listWidget.findItems('', QtCore.Qt.MatchRegExp)
for item in all_items:
  print item
```

And do whatever you need with the item =)

Comment: You can also find the other Qt.MatchFlag parameters here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum

Comment: I needed to use Qt.MatchWildcard

Answer (score 7):

```
items = []
for index in xrange(self.listWidget.count()):
     items.append(self.listWidget.item(index))
```

Answer (score 6):

Just as a note for others landing here seeking the same information about PyQt5, it's slightly different here.

As user [Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4721115/pythonic) stated above for PyQt4, you can still directly index an item using:

```
item_at_index_n = list_widget.item(n)
```

But to acquire a list of items for iteration, using an empty string and the MatchRegExp flag doesn't seem to work any more.

One way to do this in PyQt5 is:

```
all_items = list_widget.findItems('*', PyQt5.Qt.MatchWildcard)
```

I'm still getting to grips with PyQt, so there may well be an easier / simpler / more elegant way that I simply haven't come across yet.  But I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
items = []
for index in range(self.listWidget.count()):
    items.append(self.listWidget.item(index))
```

## If your wish to get the text of the items

```
for item in items:
   print(item.text())
```