# Iterating all items inside QListView using python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have a `QlistView` inside is which a checkboxes (created dynamically) with item name (`QstandardItem`). And below `Qlistview` is a checkbox named `DatacheckercheckBox1`. What I want is when this `DatacheckercheckBox1` checkbox statechanges to "Checked", all the checkboxes inside the `QlistView` should be checked. I have made a signal for `DatacheckercheckBox1` checkbox by

```
self.dlg.DatacheckercheckBox1.stateChanged.connect(self.selectAll)
```

i dont have idea in writing a method that should iterate all the items inside `Qlistview` and make the checkboxes next to it "Checked" if its not checked already.

Comment: I think below link can help you. Check it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629584/pyqt4-how-do-you-iterate-all-items-in-a-qlistwidget

Comment: Yeah i do saw the link and i dont find any method relevant in the link for QListView.

Comment: I think @SAM refers to `.findItems` method.

Comment: @ngulam. The `QListView` class doesn't have a `findItems` method. The `QStandardItemModel` class does, but it isn't really the right tool for the job, because it filters the items by matching text, rather than flags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the model to iterate over the items:

```
model = self.listView.model()
for index in range(model.rowCount()):
    item = model.item(index)
    if item.isCheckable() and item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am new to PyQT. Sorry for silly question but i wana make me myself clear. Could you please tell me more about model. I don't find any object model in documentation and also what data type does model returns? Where does the rowCount method from?

Comment: @harinish. I assumed from your question that you are using a [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html), which is a subclass of [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html). The [rowCount](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#rowCount) function is in the [Reimplemented Public Functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#reimplemented-public-functions) section.

Comment: Can i know what are you doing in item = model.item(index)?

Comment: @harinish. It [gets the item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#item) at the given index. The returned item is a [QStandardItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html), which contains the data for that row/index in the list-view.

Comment: For those who are lazy add : ```elif item.isCheckable() and item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)```right after the ```if``` condition to have the double effect check all & uncheck all